# Symfony 4: I can't autowire inside my bundle constructor

Tags: php, symfony, service, entitymanager, symfony4

My controller `PagesController` located to `vendor/dovstone/symfony-blog-admin/src/Controller` contains this code:

```
<?php 

//...

class PagesController extends Controller 
{

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        dump($em) // return null;
    }

    // ...
```

Symfony throws me this: `Type error: Too few arguments to function DovStone\Bundle\BlogAdminBundle\Controller\PagesController::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\Apps\Web\sf4\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php on line 111 and exactly 1 expected`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Copy/Paste the App\Controller\ section of your config/services.yaml file and then edit to point to your blog package.  But this would be a real hack.  Your  BlogAdminBundle should have a DI extension which takes care of creating your blog services.  It's all in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done:

```
<?php 

//...

class PagesController extends Controller 
{

protected $container;

private $em;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->container = $container;

    $this->em = $em;
    dump($em); // EntityManagerInterface;
}

// ...
```

After this, I had to clear the cache by running `php bin/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 1):

In your local Controller directory, the autowiring/autoconfig is enabled by the Yaml configuration.

In a package, you are expected to explicitly list your dependencies in the configuration. This would be setup by reading the configuration from the bundle or bridge config.

The directory you show doesn't seem to be a bundle (it doesn't have a name that indicates it - but it might still have the appropriate files), so if it is a simple package (without the Symfony framework structure to define services), you would want to add another package that was a thin layer making services from a plain-php package that it depends on.

Comment: I finally found the way to configure my bundle. It works! Thanks!

Comment: care to share @dovstone?